# Save a value in Collections and find it with Meteor

Tags: meteor, server-side, serverside-javascript

```
Values = new Meteor.Collection("values");

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    Meteor.setInterval(function() {
      Values.insert({id: Math.random(), name: "value"});
      console.log(Values.find({name: "value"}).id);
    }, 1000);
  });
}
```

I have that code and I'm trying to add a value to Values every second and find all the values I have and print them every second. However, it is not finding the values I add and is outputting:

`I2043-14:21:56.895(0)? undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find` returns a cursor, which is an object that contains the results of your search (somewhat like an array of results). It does it this way since `find` can get more than just one result, depending on the selector you passed.

It has a `forEach` similar to JS that accepts a function and receives the document, the index, and the cursor as parameters.

```
Values.find({name: "value"}).forEach(function(doc,index,cursor){
  console.log(doc.id);
});
```

Visually, a result of `find` in your case looks something like:

```
[
  {id: SOME_RANDOM_NUMBER, name: "value"},
  {id: SOME_RANDOM_NUMBER, name: "value"},
  {id: SOME_RANDOM_NUMBER, name: "value"},
  {id: SOME_RANDOM_NUMBER, name: "value"},
]
```

Comment: Any idea how I can get the length of a Collection, i. e., how many elements are in a collection? I tried `Values.find({name: "value"}).length` based on what you tell me the result of `find` in my case is, but I'm getting `undefined`.

Comment: I also tried `Values.find().count()` but it returns 426 every time :o

Comment: @user996056 `Values.find({}).count()` to return the length of the collection.

Comment: That is also returning 426 on a most definitely empty collection. Full code here: https://gist.github.com/davidgomes/464b592f4f4bed809c1b

Comment: You need to use `Values.remove(doc._id)` to remove the documents.

Comment: Yes, but which documents? I didn't add any.